# I can't display the items from the API in react App

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from API in react but I can't display the data on the page
It appears in the console but I couldn't display it on the page

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

 const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
 
 const getData = async()=>{
  await fetch(`https://629e71fe3dda090f3c19d701.mockapi.io/v1/meals`,{method:"GET"})
  .then((res) =>  res.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response));
 }

 React.useEffect(() => {
  getData()}, []);

  return (
    <div className='root'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='card'>
        <div className='juiceName'>{data.map((item)=>(<h1>{item.name}</h1>))}</div>
        <div className='juiceImage'>{data.map((item)=>(<img >{item.image}</img>))}</div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
  )
 
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't **setting** the data inside the component

Answer (score 0):

Instead of console.log the result of the request, try to set the state using your function `setData`

```
const getData = async()=>{
  await fetch(`https://629e71fe3dda090f3c19d701.mockapi.io/v1/meals`,{method:"GET"})
  .then((res) =>  res.json())
    .then((response) => setData(response));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set data in fetch response, your `useEffect()` hook doesn't work here.
Check it:
https://pastebin.com/btZB2fyB

Comment: Consider just using the StackOverflow code ticks ```` around your code instead of linking them off the site.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that when you fetched the data from the API you didn't store the response inside setData();

The second problem is that you are mapping the data incorrectly, you should add the item name and item image in the same div element.

And lastly you are using the image tag incorrectly

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        await fetch(`https://629e71fe3dda090f3c19d701.mockapi.io/v1/meals`,{method:"GET"})
        .then((res) =>  res.json())
        .then((response) => setData(response));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='root'>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='card'>
                    {
                        data.map((item, key) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={key}>
                                    <div className='juiceName'><h1>{item.name}</h1></div>
                                    <div className='juiceImage'><img src={item.image} alt={`Image of ${item.name}`}  /></div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```